# getting php variable working with embedded javascript functions

Tags: javascript, php

at the moment my code is like this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo '<audio id="player" src="../cdh/ba1.mp3">';
echo '</script>';   
echo '<a onclick="playAudio();"><i class=\'fa fa-lg fa-volume-up\'></i></a>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'function playAudio(){var audio = new Audio("../cdh/ba1.mp3");';
echo 'audio.play();}';
echo '</script>';
```

I want to get my `src="..."` & `var audio = ...` working with a php variable I have. I have variable `$row0['PIN']` which is the exact same as its filename - `$row0['PIN']` is made up of Chinese pinyin so things like `ba1` and `ba1 jia1`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$audio_file = $row['PIN']; 
$audio_path = "../cdh/$audio_file.mp3"; 
echo '<a onclick="playAudio(\''.$audio_path.'\');"><i class=\'fa fa-lg fa-volume-up\'></i></a>'; 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'function playAudio(path){var audio = new Audio(path);'; 
echo 'audio.play();}'; 
echo '</script>';
```